# How to pass selected rows data from Datatables to hidden input?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have defined a datatable in one php page and opened it in another page by boostrap modal. I want to get all cells value of selected row from datatable and pass to hidden input and want to get it into main page by submitting form.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of selected rows all td value using this:

```
var tr = $('table > tbody > tr.selected');    
var td0 = tr.find("td:eq(0)").text();
var td1 = tr.find("td:eq(1)").text();
var td2 = tr.find("td:eq(2)").text();
```